# what is the difference between cmd1 & cmd2 and cmd1 && cmd2 in shell

Tags: linux, shell

can anybody tell me what is the difference between

> cmd1 **&** cmd2 **&** ...

and

> cmd1 **&&** cmd2 **&&** ....

in shell scripting. If they differ in execution may I know how each commands are actually get executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cmd & means "run command in the background."

cmd1 && cmd2 means "run cmd1 and if it completes successfully, run cmd2 afterwards." So its like cmd2 will only be executed if cmd1 succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Assume there are cmd1 && cmd2. command2 will be executed if and only if command1 returned zero exit status.